# LRU Cache of Materialized Views?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a massive table that needs to go on a spinning rust disk. This is slow of course, but I also have an SSD that's smaller for putting MVs on. That way people can just query the MVs and get much faster retrieval.

Since the SSD is smaller, I'll have to drop the older MVs as they fall out of use, but only once the SSD is filled up.

Is there an existing system for managing this? If not, how do I write a function that knows whether there's enough space left and drops the older data? Is there a command that lets me keep the definition of the MV but empties the rows from it until another REFRESH?

Comment: Sorry, clicked the wrong button

Answer (score 1):

You can empty a materialized view and render it inaccessible with

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mv WITH NO DATA;
```

There is no way in PostgreSQL to access the free space in a file system, but you could write a PL/Python function for that.